# How to generate a single short caption for a split figure

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I want to be able to make a spit figure that only registers a single short caption in my list of figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htbp] %  figure placement: here, top, bottom, or page
       \centering
         \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image.pdf} 
        \caption[Short caption for whole fig]{caption text for first part...}
           \label{fig:g3-gen1}
    \end{figure}

        \begin{figure}[htbp] \ContinuedFloat
       \centering
         \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image.pdf} 
        \caption[I don't want to see this!]{\textit{(continued)} caption text for second part...}
       \label{fig:g3-gen2}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: An empty short caption [] does precisely what you want.

Comment: Excellent! I should have tried this.